# Calling image from Mysql DB path PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

Hello dear Overflowers!

I have a little code that so far works so well,
it gets the corresponding Image ID to the corresponding House ID, also Caption and filename are no problem!
I just fail at displaying the image...  :(
`

```
include("functions/config.php");
$images_dir = "/some/url/that/is/correct/cms/houses/";


$query = "SELECT houses.*, gallery_photos.* ".
"FROM houses LEFT JOIN gallery_photos ".
"ON houses.id = gallery_photos.photo_category"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$house_id = $row['id'];
$photo_category = $row['photo_category'];
$photo_caption = $row['photo_caption'];
$photo_filename = $row['photo_filename'];



echo "House ID ". $house_id. " - ". $photo_category." - ". $photo_caption." -       <img src='".$images_dir.$photo_filename."' />";

echo "<br />";
}
?>`
```

So as said, everything get selected well, even the image path is correct when you click Image Info in the browser, but I simply do not get the image to display, am I missing something very trivial here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that your URL is correct? Just right click on image and try to open it in a new window. The image must be opened or you'll get 404 or something else. Just in order to test your URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right guys, finally found the mistake, which I hope that with my anwser, some pople in the future can avoid it!

As it seems some Hosts do not like some of the PHP naming conventions, so what I had to do, so the files would actually be stored in the folder, was change the command to get them from "Tmp/In memory" to the final destination folder.
For better understanding, here what I changed :

```
copy($photos_uploaded['tmp_name'][$counter],    
$images_dir . '/' . $filename);
```

to

```
move_uploaded_file($photos_uploaded['tmp_name'][$counter],    
$images_dir . '/' . $filename);
```

I hope no one else ever has to fiddle this long and spend so much money on Coffee ever again.
Thanks to all that tried to help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Check Image Name in Table as well as in folder where you store particular image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='".$images_dir.$photo_filename."' />
```

It misses like .jpg or .png whatever the extension of your img is

Comment: Strange, to me it seems like it should work.  Try echo $images_dir.$photo_filename. and be sure it's correct. Also if it's a jpeg $photo_filename should end with .jpg and not .jpeg

Comment: When I echo the Image_dir and Image filename I get and absolute path to the image like this : http://my-site.com/var/www/vhosts/my-site.com/httpdocs/my-site/cms/houses/5953.jpg 
*Changed the right webadress to my-site*

Comment: And what's the path of your .php file? if http://my-site.com/var/www/vhosts/my-site.com/httpdocs/my-site/cms/houses/5953.jpg is your total path and not the relative path it could work if you put http:// in front of it.
So like <img src='http://".$images_dir.$photo_filename."' />

Answer (score 0):

Check with tool like Firebug what is the path in `src` attribute of `img` element. Then copy this link and paste it in browser to see if it opens (with your website name - so if link is '/img/houses/house1.jpg' then you paste to browser 'www.mypage.com/img/houses/house1.jpg').
If it does not then:

- Check if path is correct (it will count from web root folder) (your path should be probably like '/cms/houses/5953.jpg')
- Check of path has correct letter sizes ('house' vs. 'House')
- Check if you can open file on server (maybe file is corrupted)
- Check if you have rights to read file

Comment: After about 5 hours and a few too many coffee cups, I found the mistake. Everything was correct, except for the fact that I had 1 white space that was being compiled by PHP, and that killed the Path to the pictures directory on the upload process. So the pre upload was fine, but in the folder move sequence I had an error, thus the image not being moved to its final destination, creating just a blank image file, with no image behind it. I only always checked if there where files in the Folder, never thought about opening them to see if the image was actually there...too Trivial mistake...Thanks